# XAMPP Won't Start After PHP 8.1 Update and No Errors in Logs (Except MySQL)

Tags: php, windows, xampp

I've followed all of the standard instructions to do the update and it looks like it starts and then it stops.

1:00:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Control Panel
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Windows Version:  Enterprise  64-bit
1:00:50 PM  [main]  XAMPP Version: 7.4.11
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Control Panel Version: 3.2.4  [ Compiled: Jun 5th 2019 ]
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Running with Administrator rights - good!
1:00:50 PM  [main]  XAMPP Installation Directory: "c:\xampp"
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Checking for prerequisites
1:00:50 PM  [main]  All prerequisites found
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Initializing Modules
1:00:50 PM  [mysql]     XAMPP MySQL is already running on port 3306
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Enabling autostart for module "Apache"
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Enabling autostart for module "MySQL"
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Starting Check-Timer
1:00:50 PM  [main]  Control Panel Ready
1:00:50 PM  [Apache]    Autostart active: starting...
1:00:50 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
1:00:50 PM  [mysql]     Autostart aborted: MySQL is already running
1:00:51 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
1:00:57 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums

mysql_error.log shows ... 
InnoDB: using atomic writes.
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery from checkpoint LSN=246370267
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.14 started; log sequence number 246370276; transaction id 9018
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2022-02-02 13:01:53 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.

Answer (score 0):

Installed a new version of XAMPP (after uninstall) and reconfiguring the new version solved this issue.